# How to prevent repeated casting of HTMLFormElement in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

Currently I'm looping over the elements of a form using the following code, but I'm wondering how I could eliminate the repeated casts `as HTMLFormElement`. If I exclude them I get a warning that the `Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Element'`.

```js
Array.from((e.target as HTMLFormElement).elements)
  .filter(el => (el as HTMLFormElement).type === 'radio')
  .filter(el => (el as HTMLFormElement).checked === true)
```

While I can hoist up the cast to an `Array`, such as:

```js
const els = Array.from((e.target as HTMLFormElement).elements) as Array<HTMLFormElement>
els
  .filter(el => el.type === 'radio')
  .filter(el => el.checked === true)
```

It seems seems like I should be able to simply define/assert the type rather than needing to cast it.

Is there a reason this doesn't work equally as well?

```js
const els: Array<HTMLFormElement> = Array.from((e.target as HTMLFormElement).elements
```

Full context is a React component.

```js
export const Form = ({ children }: FormProps) => {
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const els = Array.from((e.target as HTMLFormElement).elements)
    els.filter(el => el instanceof HTMLInputElement && el.type === 'radio' && el.checked === true)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {children}
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeated assertions are superfluous because you only need a single `.filter` callback. Also, the `.elements` collection will be composed of *control elements*, like inputs and buttons - not `HTMLFormElement` (which only the containing `<form>` is) - two of your `as` are asserting inaccurately.

You can get rid of the assertions entirely by testing in the JavaScript whether the element being iterated over is an `<input>` (which is safer).

```
Array.from((e.target as HTMLFormElement).elements)
    .filter(el => el instanceof HTMLInputElement && el.type === 'radio' && el.checked === true);
```

> Is there a reason this doesn't work equally as well?

Well, it would need to be typed properly, to start with - but it'd be easier to let TypeScript infer the type automatically (a generic `Element` type, as it does now, is fine) and not bother trying to correct it.

Since it sounds like this is in an event handler, if the element the listener is attached to is typed properly, you could refer to it again instead of having to cast `e.target`.

```
const form = document.querySelector('form')!;
form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
    Array.from(form.elements)
        .filter(el => el instanceof HTMLInputElement && el.type === 'radio' && el.checked);
});
```

though if there's more than one form on the page, you'll need a generic

```
const form = document.querySelector<HTMLFormElement>('form')!;
```

If the resulting filtered array needs to be typed, [the only option is to be somewhat repetitive](https://stackoverflowcom/q/44390395) by adding `as Array<HTMLInputElement>` to the end, or by making `.filter` generic.

---

If this is React, there are better approaches:

- By referencing the `.currentTarget` from the event handler, React will recognize that the element the listener was attached to will be the same as the `.currentTarget` without the need for casting:

  ```
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const els = Array.from(e.currentTarget.elements)
  ```

  (In contrast, the `.target` may be any element. `.currentTarget` often works better with TypeScript.)
- Vanilla DOM manipulation methods should be avoided in React. Instead of accessing the children from the form element, it would be more elegant to access the children's *state* from a state variable. Controlled components generally make code easier to manage than uncontrolled components.

Comment: Ah thank you. Yes, it is a React event handler, so my listener is capturing a `React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>` event, so I don't know that there's a way to type the element/listener correctly. But I did end up using your `instanceOf` suggestion to drop the repetition. Thanks for the clarity.